# Airflow - preserve the state in retry

Tags: airflow

My Airflow dag sends an HTTP PUT request every hour with the hour in the body.
In case of failure, I want that the retry's request will contain the original hour in the body (even after several days).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways you could achieve this, but I'd suggest having a look into Airflows XCOM: https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#concepts-xcom

A simple example to suit your case would be to create a DAG with 2 nodes - NodeA and NodeB.

1. NodeA runs and stores the current time in XCOM
2. NodeB runs, retrieves the time from the XCOM of NodeA, and makes a PUT request with that value in the body.

If you were wanting to re-trigger the PUT request in future, you would only need to clear NodeB in the DAG. When it runs again, it will retrieve same time that was originally stored in the XCOM of NodeA.

Comment: Make sense, thanks. Could you please mention shortly the other ways?

Comment: No problem, please consider accepting my answer if it was useful to you! Other solutions involve external tracking/triggering of dags. You could look into triggering a dagrun via airflow cli or custom python script and providing a time stamp as a config parameter. This means re triggering a dagrun in the future would always use the same time stamp in the config. It’s not as nice a nice solution so I would strongly suggest using xcom.